# How to avoid django creating table for manager?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am pretty new to python and django. My question is mounted on model managers, if they are created in models.py and I run syncdb a table is created for that manager. Is there a particular reason for that? And if not how do I avoid that? I searched through the django docs and djangobook but couldn't find an answer to these questions. Any hints will be greatly appreciated.

```
class CompaniesManager(models.Model):
    ...

class Companies(models.Model):    
    ...
    company_objects = CompaniesManager()
```

This creates tables companies_companies and companies_companiesmanager ...

Comment: Can you post your model manager? I'm quite sure that Django does not create tables for them.

Comment: Ok I edited my question with some code that hopefully clarifies :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Models and model managers are different things. Tables are not created for model managers.

Comment: Thanks for the swift answer, so probably I am doing something plainly wrong since you say so. :-) Maybe it has to do with the way I create the manager example model Companies and its manager declared like so: `class CompaniesManager(models.Model):` Does that mean I make it a model aswell?

Comment: @Johi: Managers should inherit from models.Manager, not models.Model.

Comment: Any class that inherits from `models.Model` will be a model. A model manager will inherit from `models.Manager`.

Comment: Thank you so much, I do not know how I could have missed that :-)